# What is the best practice for an icon placeholder?

Tags: icons, image, themes, customisation, placeholder

I'm designing a bunch of eCommerce themes which come with a design file - the file is a low fidelity version. In the high fidelity design there are various times when icons are used, for example:

[image]

When installing the theme there will be no icon by default which works well however in the design files by default there should be an icon to indicate that they can be added.

**What would be the best practice for an icon "placeholder"?**

Currently i've tried the following:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Much more representative than the fixed element is the action to do.

In other words, instead of looking for a graphic element for *placeholder*, easier and better to recognize is `insert icon` or `add icon` here.

Anyway, in page layout applications, the placeholder is represented by the blue square with the eight transformation points:

[image: frame]

About the action:

[image: icons]